# Is there any research work that shows that we should explicitly mark the word boundaries for 1D CNNs?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, natural-language-processing, reference-request, embeddings

I'm doing character embedding for NLP tasks using one-dimensional convolutional neural networks (see [Chiu and Nichols (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08308) for the motivation). I haven't found any empirical evidence of whether or not marking the word boundaries makes a difference. As an example, a 1-D CNN with kernel size 2 would take `"the"` as input and use `{"th", "he"}` in its filters. But if I explicitly marked the boundaries it would give me `{"t", "th", "he", "h"}`.

Is there a go-to paper or project that definitively answers this question?

Comment: The idea of "character embedding" comes from [Chiu and Nichols (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08308). Character embeddings from the CNN are fed into a word-level LSTM.